# How change default font of hyperlinks in Abiword?

Tags: fonts, text-editor, abiword

Abiword - hyperlinks all displaying with blue, underlined font.

I would like to change this so all hyperlinks display with a particular font of my choosing. How do I do it?

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- Abiword 3.0.2

Comment: Pls see above. Thank you.